# Adjustment two video in matlab

Tags: matlab, video, image-processing

I  capture my computer screen and a mirror using  a camera.
Now I want to adjustment the screen to the mirror,  for every pixel in the screen to adjustment a pixel in the mirror
I attach a frame from the video.

I am looking for code or idea.[image]

I add some example of images:

[image]
[image]

[image] [image]

Comment: See the link [SURF_FLANN](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.1/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html)

Comment: Is there matlab function like FlannBasedMatcher?

Comment: Here is the link for whole program [Matlab_surf](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28300-opensurf-including-image-warp)

Comment: Hi, i am adding these comments as answer so that others can see answer easily...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm you are looking for is keypoint detector and matcher. There are several algorithms that can do the job (SURF,SIFT,ORB,FREAK etc) the process involves three steps.

1. Feature Point detection.
2. Generation of Descriptors for each keypoint of template image and target image.

The algorithms for the two stages are SURF, SIFT, ORB etc See opencv Feature detection section for more details.

3. Matching of the keypoints in two images

This can be done by using KNN match, FLANN based matcher, BRUTEFORCE matcher etc.

Here are the links in matlab and opencv.

[MatLab_SURF](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28300-opensurf-including-image-warp)

[Opencv_Feature Detection](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html)

The reason for SURF algorithm failure in your case:

While matching two images are objects in two different scenarios, we need to take the following conditions into consideration:

1. Which transformation has occurred between the images, is it affine or perspective or just a translation or rotation etc...

   In your case it is looking like perspective transformation...
2. Does images are rich in texture and quality.
   In your case images are rich in texture but poor in quality or loss of details may be they were captured by low resolution camera.

See my answer for a similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920483/object-recognition-performance-not-good/11921395#11921395)

My first suggestion is First capture a data set that has more quality. So that it is easier for Keypoint detection algorithm to find Good Key points, Once a basic algorithm is ready , then go for improvements to make it work for Poor resolution datasets.

Comment: I am sorry but this algorithm don't work properly and not give me the correct answer. even not close. I looking for algorithm that consider that the movies are transformation of each other

Comment: Hi, can you upload some sample images of your dataset, so that i can know what is the problem exatly.

Comment: Thanks, I will shoot a new movie